# Is Babel still required in 2018?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm learning JavaScript right now and some said that after I learned HTML and CSS and vanilla Javascript I need to have the knowledge about ES6/ES2015. When I watch tutorials on Youtube it says that we need Babel or something like that for the browser to read it. So I'm wondering because that video is not that old (but still old). Is it still necessary to have Babel or I should skip this Babel thing?

Comment: Actually the `babel` is a transpiler and a transpiler will be always required to use cutting edge features because all the browser vendors don't implement all the language features simultaneously.

Comment: Babel makes your shiny code understandable by obsolete browsers. Keep on writing new syntax and run it through Babel. You don't need to understand or learn Babel. You only need to run your code through it.

Comment: haha, that situation when The Alpha comments on Alpha_Bords. But actually you don't need Babel until you notice that something is not working in some browsers. Until that point I would completely ignore it.

Comment: @smnbbrv, didn't see that coming :-)

Comment: Thank you So much. To be honest Im really Flattered how this website works and It give me ease because Im a complete Beginner in Web Development. But I'm not gonna abuse it though and will keep coding until my fingers bleed. haha Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Keep your questions specific and useful for future users and you'll fit right in. Happy coding!

Comment: Just a side note: In English, we basically only capitalize at the beginning of a sentence or if the word is a proper noun or the "I" pronoun (but not others like "he"). When you capitalize other words, it makes it hard to read your writing. FWIW.

Comment: Ok thanks for the Tip. I'll keep that to my head next time

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6

Comment: possible duplicate of some [Is Babel still needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[babeljs]+title%3Astill)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Babel](https://babeljs.io) is a JavaScript-to-JavaScript compiler, sometimes called a *transpiler*, that converts code written with one set of features (for instance, those in ES2015 and later) into code that can be run in a JavaScript environment that doesn't support those features. (There are others, Babel is just one quite popular one.)

Whether you use Babel to transpile your ES2015+ code to ES5 is entirely up to you, and depends on what target environments you want to support. If you want to support any version of Internet Explorer¹ (including IE11), for instance, you'll need to transpile. If you only need to support cutting-edge Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, or other environments where you can count on the features you're using being there (like up-to-date Node.js installations), you don't.

Kangax has a set of [handy tables](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for what JavaScript engines and/or browsers support which of the more modern features of JavaScript (not just ES2015, but ES2016, ES2017, etc.).

Babel (and tools like it) are useful beyond just using the most-recently-standardized features, in at least two ways:

1. You can use Babel (and similar) to take advantage of features that are likely to be standardized soon, even though they're not well-supported yet. For example, the basics of public class fields haven't changed in a long time, but [the proposal they're in](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is still (as of this writing in June 2018) at Stage 3 (and has been back and forth between Stage 2 and Stage 3 a couple of times) for reasons unrelated to public class fields, and not even cutting-edge browsers like Chrome, Firefox, and Edge have support for public class fields yet. But it's common, these days, to use class fields via a transpiler.
2. You can write your own Babel (or similar) transform to add your own features to JavaScript for your own project (or use ones other people have written), even if those features are never going to be part of JavaScript or used outside your project.

---

¹ Note: [Internet Explorer is sunset as of June 15th 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/internet-explorer-11-end-of-support) in most versions of Windows. But there's an "Internet Explorer" mode in Microsoft Edge, and heaven help us, it actually removes features like template literals, `for-of`, etc. from the JavaScript environment in that mode.

Comment: regarding your comments " If you want to support any version of IE (including IE11), for instance, you'll need to transpile. If you only need to support cutting-edge Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, or other environments where you can count on the features you're using being there (like up-to-date Node.js installations), you don't."

Please note few days earlier microsoft announce to discontinue IE  and deploy a new version of browser which basic core will be chromium based , so technically on windows with IE (chromium based) you dont need babel in future. Thanks

Comment: here is announcement on windows central : https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-building-chromium-powered-web-browser-windows-10

Comment: @DineshNagari - You're confusing IE and Edge. IE will never be Chromium-based, and if you need to support IE (even the aging "latest", IE11), you need to transpile. *Edge* (which already has quite an up-to-date JS engine) is what's being replaced with a Chromium-based thing. What we know for sure is that Anaheim (the new Edge) will use Blink (Chrome's rendering engine). We don't have any confirmation from Microsoft that it will use V8 (Chrome's JavaScript engine) rather than Chakra (MS's), although the fact that Microsoft staff have done commits to the v8/v8 project suggests that it will.

Comment: thanks for the clarification Crowder, But no one will be using IE for sure once they deprecate it and when Micorsoft will start to render update for edge (based on V8 instead of chakra) , and its going to happen soon they are actively working on it.

Comment: @DineshNagar - And people didn't use IE6 for more than a decade after IE7 came out, either. ;-) (And again: We don't *know* that they'll be using V8 instead of Chakra. We know they'll be using Blink instead of EdgeHTML.)

Comment: (We do, now, know that they're using V8 in the Chromium-version of Edge. They'll continue to use Chakra for Windows Universal Apps, though.)

Answer (score 22):

Not to be off topic--as a beginner I recommend staying away from tooling and configurations. It can be overwhelming, especially in JS land. Just focus on learning, tooling will come later. You can start using ES6 right away without any tooling.

One way is to use an online REPL or playground. One tool I like is https://stackblitz.com this website let's you get a real feel for importing modules from `npm` to assist your code. If you are on Chrome, you can open the developer console and see the messages you send from the playground to the developer console.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Here is a playground I made to get you started

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t3wxth?file=index.js

Comment: Maybe that's nitpicking but i would say such an REPL/playground is a tool anyway, and if it supports ES2015+ and other unsupported features then it's doing more or less the same thing as babel is. Likewise if someone is seriously thinking about development he should practise beeing overwhelmed, to the point where - eventually - beeing overwhelmed starts beeing just normal.

Comment: From my own learning experience. At some point I started to realize that babel as a tool provides leverage in terms of thinking about what javascript is and how it works. Making it worthwhile to engage with